# Using the 'at' command

Tags: bash, shell-script, at

This part of my script outputs

```
at: garbled time
```

for every index in the loop, where `showRestNotification` is a function defined previous to this call

```
for i in {0..5}
 do
  at ${sleepTimes[$i]} -f showRestNotification 
done
```

where given

```
echo ${sleepTimes[0]}
```

the output looks like

```
05/06/17 19:15
```

How can I reformat my variable so that it will work with the at command? I need the date to stay however as it is imperative to the function of my script.

Edit:

sleepTimes function

```
generateSleepTimes()
{
  oldIFS=$IFS
  IFS=: splitTime=(${wakeUpTime##*-})
  wakeUpHours=${splitTime[0]}
  wakeUpMinutes=${splitTime[1]}

  if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
         currentHours=$(date +'%H')
         currentMinutes=$(date +'%M')
  elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
          currentHours=$(gdate +'%H')
          currentMinutes=$(gdate +'%M')
  fi


  if [[ $wakeUpHours -lt $currentHours ]]; then
        IFS=$oldIFS
        wakeUpTime="$wakeUpTime tomorrow"

  elif [[ $wakeUpHours -eq $currentHours && $wakeUpMinutes -lt $currentMinutes ]]; then
        IFS=$oldIFS
        wakeUpTime="$wakeUpTime tomorrow"

  else
        IFS=$oldIFS

        wakeUpTime="$wakeUpTime today"

  fi

  if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
          tempTime=$(date -d "$wakeUpTime - 15 minutes" +"%D %H:%M")

  elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
          tempTime=$(gdate -d "$wakeUpTime - 15 minutes" +"%D %H:%M")
  fi

  if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
          sleepTimes[6]=$(date -d "$tempTime" +"%D %H:%M")

  elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
          sleepTimes[6]=$(gdate -d "$tempTime" +"%D %H:%M")
  fi

  for i in {5..0}
  do
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
            sleepTimes[$i]=$(date -d "${sleepTimes[$i+1]} - 1 hour" +"%D %H:%M")

    elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
            sleepTimes[$i]=$(gdate -d "${sleepTimes[$i+1]} - 1 hour" +"%D %H:%M")
    fi
  done
  echo "${sleepTimes[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Please provide the source of `sleepTimes[ ]` function. Its much easy to make modifications there.

Comment: If `showRestNotification` is a function this isn't going to work anyway, so the question may be moot.

Comment: Wait, hang on, `at -f ${sleepTimes[$i]}` uses `${sleepTimes[$i]}` as a filename. What's meant to be the file?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Check the edited code sorry i copied an older version. How do i run a function previously described in the script then? it would be preferred to keep it this way rather than move that function to its own file.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Updated with code

Comment: @A.Epstein The `generateSleepTimes` function is unimportant to the `at` job. It's the `showRestNotification` function that needs to be available in the session that the `at` job runs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command

```
at -f ${sleepTimes[$i]} showRestNotification
```

instructs `at` to run `${sleepTimes[$i]}` on the time `showRestNotification`.

1. The time specification is garbled, i.e. not on a format recognizable by `at` on your system.
2. `at` reads from standard input (or from a file when `-f` is used).

You will need to read the documentation for `at` on your system to see what format the time specification need to be in. On my system (not Linux), it says it should be on the format `[[cc]yy]mmddHHMM[.SS]`, i.e. `201705061915` for 19:15 on the 6th of May 2017.

Furthermore, since `at` reads the commands to run from standard input (or from a file when `-f` is used), you will have to provide it with a shell script that contains the definition of the function you want to run, along with the correct call to it, for example:

```
#/bin/sh

# this is "job.sh"

showRestNotification () {
    # ...
}

showRestNotification
```

Then,

```
at -f job.sh -t 201705061915
```

or

```
at 201705061915 <job.sh
```

Since `at` will run the specified file using `/bin/sh` you will need to invoke a `bash` script containing the function definition and invocation from `job.sh` if you want to use `bash`-specific shell constructs.

---

A portability hint for your code:

```
date () {
    case "$OSTYPE" in
      darwin*) command gdate "$@" ;;
      linux*)  command date  "$@" ;;
      *) printf 'Unsupported OS type: %s\n' "$OSTYPE" >&2
         exit 1 ;;
     esac
}
```

Then just use

```
sleepTimes[$i]="$(date -d "${sleepTimes[$i+1]} - 1 hour" +"%Y%m%d%H%M")"
```

without having to test `$OSTYPE` all over the place.

Comment: I tried that time formatting but was using the -t option should i not do that? and how do i run a function previously defined in the same script instead of a file i would rather not place that function in a separate file

Comment: Using `-t` is fine, in which case the argument to that flag should be on the format I described (`[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`). You can not pass a function invocation to `at` since `at` will be running the job in a separate session where the function is not defined. The job has to be self-contained.

Comment: I got the jobs to work and i am definitely going to implement that portability hint thanks for that. However when the time of the job comes it does actually happen although the job is present with a `atq` command. I call the at job like this now `at -f ./noti.sh -t ${sleepTimes[$i]}` where noti.sh is in the same directory as the script calling the `at` command what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @A.Epstein Is the `${sleepTimes[$i]}` on the right format? According to the Linux `at` manual, it should be `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`.

Comment: some of the times generate look like this `201705062214 201705070014 201705070214 201705070414` i used what you mentioned in your suggestion to get it in this format and its the first time i didn't get the garbled time output however the job never seems to do its job lol

Comment: Additionally I realized I don't want to just subtract an hour I want to subtract an hour and 30 minutes each time how do I do that? All my attempts have led to the jobs been scheduled for 00:00